# Time Duration Picker For Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, web-development, bootstrap

Is there a [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) (native or 3rd party) widget that allows the user to specify a **Time Duration**?

To elaborate; the user is specifying how long a task can take. It can take 1 minute, 1 hour and 1 minute, 1 day 1 hour and 1 minute, 1 week ..., 1 month and so on.

So the units (minutes, hours, etc) will change according to how the user desires. The only widget I have found is one that lets you [specify a time](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#disables_date_picker) (hours, minutes, seconds). I am thinking I can create many number inputs (one for month, one for week and so on) but I dont want to reinvent the wheel if there is a widget out there.

Are you aware of a widget that allows a user to specify a time duration in months, weeks, days, hours and minutes?

Answer (score 1):

I found this: https://github.com/koss-lebedev/bootstrap-duration-picker
it is easy to use, I like it.
This plug-in add bootstrap on another jquery-duration-picker. To use this plug-in you have to include the .js and .css that they are in the `src` folder.
So it looks like:

[image]

Unfortunately, the months are not implemented...

**Usage**

```
$('.duration-picker').durationPicker();

// or

$('.duration-picker').durationPicker({
    lang: 'en',
    formatter: some_function // a function that gets numbers displayed in input and returns a formatted one,
    showSeconds: false // defines whether to show seconds or not 
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23836)

Comment: No problem, your answer may answer the question, just be sure to check out [the tour](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site and our [answer quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/133) to improve it, thanks:)

Comment: I updated my answer is correct now?

Comment: Well, it seems that it doesn't include the month feature which is ok but might warrant a downvote (or hopefully just a comment) from the op but also you copied and pasted that info above from the linked site, something that's definitely frowned upon. If you could go through what the OP wanted and their requirements and state how this software (library) answers their question. Also, anything copied and pasted needs to be in a quote form (use the > to start a block quote).